# Output format problem with file based array/list in Python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, dns

OK, so the use case here is I am taking a list of FQDN's (one per line) that are in a plain text file and feeding that into a list. The Goal is to iterate through the list and output a static-stub DNS zone statement per list element instance. This is the code I have thus far:

```
with open('/stubtest.txt') as f:
    staticstubs=list(f)


i = 0

while i < len(staticstubs) :
  print  'zone ' + '"' + staticstubs[i] + '"' + '  {'
  print  '   type static-stub;'
  print  '   server-addresses { 10.10.10.1, 10.10.10.2 };'
  print  ' };'
  print ' '
  i += 1
```

The problem is the format of the output is not correct. I wind up with this:

```
zone "domain1.com
"  {
   type static-stub;
   server-addresses { 10.10.10.1, 10.10.10.2 };
 };

zone "domain2.com
"  {
   type static-stub;
   server-addresses { 10.10.10.1, 10.10.10.2 };
 };

zone "domain3.net
"  {
   type static-stub;
   server-addresses { 10.10.10.1, 10.10.10.2 };
 };
```

However, if I define an array statically within the actual script file instead of reading in the file, I get the correct output with the same code:

```
staticstubs = ["domain1.com", "domain2.com", "domain3.com"]
i = 0

while i < len(staticstubs) :
  print  'zone ' + '"' + staticstubs[i] + '"' + '  {'
  print  '   type static-stub;'
  print  '   server-addresses { 10.10.10.1, 10.10.10.2 };'
  print  ' };'
  print ' '
  i += 1
```

Static array output:

```
zone "domain1.com"  {
   type static-stub;
   server-addresses { 10.10.10.1, 10.10.10.2 };
 };

zone "domain2.com"  {
   type static-stub;
   server-addresses { 10.10.10.1, 10.10.10.2 };
 };

zone "domain3.com"  {
   type static-stub;
   server-addresses { 10.10.10.1, 10.10.10.2 };
 };
```

I need to be able to feed the FQDN list file into an array/list and get the same output format as when using the statically defined array. I'm racking my brain on this a bit. Any help would be much appreciated (python version is 2.7.5)

Answer (score 0):

When you read from the file the end of the line has a new line. Try stripping the new line with `staticstubs[i].replace("\n", "")`
Another option would be to use

```
f.read().splitlines()
```

To create the list

Comment: Perfect! both options worked.  Thanks so much for the help!